# How to get attribute for selected option ONLY within an active tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, select

I have an image-picker that goes through each of my categories and outputs every title/image of every post. Each of these categories, along with all the posts are held inside of a bootstrap tab-pane. The problem is that when the image picker generates all the post images, each tab-pane, whether it's active or not, has a selected image.

I was going to go along with route of limiting only the active tab-pane to be allowed a "selected" image, where all other tab-panes have no images with class "selected", but have decided to go with another route:

I'm basically trying to locate the image that's selected (has class "selected"), ONLY if the parent-parent-parent(x3) element is selected (has class "active"). Here's an example:

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="someID1">
    <ul class="thumbnails image_picker_selector">
        <li>
            <div class="thumbnail selected">
                <img class="image_picker_image" src="something.jpg">
            </div>
        </li>
        ... <!-- More list options -->
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="someID2">
    <!--  This tab also has one div with classes "thumbnail selected" -->
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="someID3">
    <!--  This tab also has one div with classes "thumbnail selected" -->
</div>
```

I've found a code that gets ALL of the "src" attributes from all selected thumbnails, but how would I go about getting ONLY from the active tab?

Here was the code to get all thumbnail selected src attributes:

```
var req = $("div[class='thumbnail selected']").children('img');
var imagessource = [];
$(req).each(function (datakey, datavalue) {
    src = $(datavalue).attr('src');
    imagessource.push(src);
});
console.log(imagessource);
```

Comment: Something like `$( "active thumbnails selected" )"` https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after? The jquery selector supports css selector, so no need to write `div[class='...']` unless you want to match exactly a div that have just those two class names in that order

```
$('.tab-pane.active div.thumbnail.selected').children('img')
```

---

Just a suggestion (You don't need to wrap each img in a jQuery wrapper)
And [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) seems like a better fit for the job

```
var imagessource = $(req).map((idx, elm) => elm.src)
```

And you don't need to wrap `req` another time in `$()` since it's already a jquery object. So you can just write

```
req.map(....)
```

result:

```
var 
req = $('.tab-pane.active div.thumbnail.selected img'),
imagessource = req.map((idx, elm) => elm.src);

console.log(imagessource);
```

Comment: you can shorten it to just $('.tab-pane.active div.thumbnail.selected img')